# WPF styles cast exception

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml, styles

I'm trying to define fonts which can be reference by many style elements:

```
<System:String x:Key="FontFamilyDefault">Arial</System:String>
<System:Int32  x:Key="FontSizeDefault">18</System:Int32>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="FontColourDefault" Color="Black"/>
```

and my style refers to it by:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Control}" x:Key="myStyle1">
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{StaticResource FontSizeDefault}" />
    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{StaticResource FontFamilyDefault}" />
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource FontColourDefault}" />
</Style>
```

and the control refers myStyle1:

```
<Style TargetType="TextBox" BasedOn="{StaticResource myStyle1}" />
```

I get the following runtime exception:
**Unable to cast object of type 'System.String' to type 'System.Windows.Media.FontFamily'.**
if I comment out:

```
<Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{StaticResource FontFamilyDefault}
```

then get this exception on the size conersion:
 **Specified cast is not valid**.

can anyone suggest how to convert string to fontfamily and how to specify the font size in xaml?

thanks in advance

Comment: Why do use `StaticResources` when setting the `Value` of a `Property` at all ? If you do not have any requirement to do that I would assign the values directly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a StaticResource with the FontFamily type ..

```
<FontFamily x:Key="CockpitFont" >Verdana</FontFamily>
```

Comment: You're doing it the right way. The only thing that is different is the type. Try changing it to System:Double instead of Int32